# Attributes for passing data in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery and in order to perform dynamic computations I need to store some information along an anchor tag, such as:

```
<a href="blah.html" username="some value" age="12" address="blah">click</a>
```

Of course this code will not pass validation, and since I need more than one data to store using `rel` attribute, for example, wouldn't be enough. I know HTML5 addresses this issue ,but int the meantime (until HTMl5 is fully accepted) what other options do I have?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prefix your address attribute with 'data-' and access it using [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) like so:

```
<a href="blah.html" username="some value" age="12" data-address="blah">click</a>


alert($("a").data("address"));
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qyLKC/1/)

Comment: @Joel - That is valid HTML5, I'm not sure what happens when you run it through a HTML4 validator. If you're using jQuery to extract the data, you shouldn't run into any problems regardless of your doctype. Take a look at this: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/